# how to set value in fmt:Format from jquery function

Tags: jquery, jsp-tags

i need to set the value in fmt:FormatNumber dynamically from jquery.

```
<div id="total">
   <fmt:formatNumber value='${totalValue}' type="currency" maxFractionDigits="2"  minFractionDigits="2"/>
</div>
```

i have tried this

```
$('#total').find('fmt\\:formatNumber').attr('value', 'newValue');
```

and this is not working for me..can you people get me out of this.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing JSP tags with client-side script. When you call `<fmt:formatNumber />` you're asking the server to print out literal text to the browser e.g. `$20,000.99`, so in your source code it would look like:

```
<div id="total">&pound;20,000.00</div>
```

You could wrap the `<fmt:formatNumber />` in a span, e.g.

**JSP:**

```
<div id="total">
   <span><fmt:formatNumber value='${totalValue}' type="currency" maxFractionDigits="2"  minFractionDigits="2"/></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#total').find('span').attr('value', 'newValue');
```

OR you could just use the existing `#total` div:

```
$('#total').attr('value', 'newValue');
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion..but its not working for me.the value is not changing. i want to change the value only and want the currency and decimal places as it is..is there any other way.? please help